# Java Stream missing a code coverage branch

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, code-coverage, jacoco

For the following, Jacoco says all 4 branches are covered.

```
list.stream()
  .forEach(item -> item.type.equals("Good") && item.expired == false);
```

However for this snippet, and running the same set of tests, Jacoco says there's 1 missing branch.

```
list.stream()
  .filter(item -> item.type.equals("Good") && item.expired == false)
  .findFirst()
  .get()
```

How can this be?

```
psuedocode:
public void testA() {
  // new Item(item type, is expired)
  item1 = new Item("Good", false);
  item1 = new Item("Good", true);
  item1 = new Item("Electricity", false);
  item1 = new item("Water", true);

  Item result = service.methodToTest(item1, item2, item3, item4);

  assertThat(result).isEqualTo(item1);
}
```

Comment: can you include the test you wrote for it?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `forEach` in this snippet is invoked for every element (although it does not do anything - it produces a `boolean` and forgets it):

```
list.stream()
  .forEach(item -> item.type.equals("Good") && item.expired == false);
```

Whereas in the following snippet you're filtering elements by a predicate:

```
list.stream()
  .filter(item -> item.type.equals("Good") && item.expired == false)
  .findFirst()
  .get()
```

You need to check, that elements that do not fulfill the predicate are filtered out and vice versa. This way you have 2 branches to check.